# Android Layout: Creating a 2x3 grid - trying to avoid nesting LinearLayout with weights

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I need to create a 2 by 3 grid, where all the screen space is divided evenly - and I know that nesting linear layouts with weights is bad practice, so I'm looking for an alternative solution.

I need the space to be divided evenly, regardless of screen size - 3 rows with 2 columns each.

From what I understand, GridView/GridLayout/TableLayout will not automatically fill space or divide it evenly - so is there any alternative that will suit my needs?

I know you can set the Layout Params programmatically - is this better practice than using nested LinearLayouts with weights?

Thanks for your help

EDIT: To be clear, I intend to display six images, two in each row with three rows.  I simply want to divide the screen space evenly - that is, have three rows of the same height, and two columns in each row of the same width.

EDIT2: This is what I'm using as of now, though I am still interested if someone has a better recommendation. I'm not sure this is better than using nested layout_weight values

- In my XML I've weighted 3 LinearLayout containers to each take up 1/3 of the available screen height using layout_weight. (XML has a LinearLayout as it's root element)
- Each container as two images as children, for which I'm setting the width programmatically as follows:

  ```
      //Get appropiate width
      DisplayMetrics metrics = con.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
      int width = metrics.widthPixels / 2;
      //Set gif views to correct width - half of screen size
      teamViewGif1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
      teamViewGif2.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
      teamViewGif3.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
      teamViewGif4.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
      teamViewGif5.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
      teamViewGif6.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
  ```

Again, I'm still interested if anyone has a better solution or advice

EDIT3: Changed layout to use relative layout instead, and now setting both the images height and width programmatically.

Comment: `From what I understand, GridView/GridLayout/TableLayout will not automatically fill space or divide it evenly` Who told you that? A GridView is **exactly** what you need.

Comment: Cool I'll give it a shot, must have been reading something outdated, thanks

Comment: So I'm not sure that GridView is not exactly what I'm looking for - I don't want a scrolling view, and it is overly complicated to add an entire custom adapter when all I need is to display six images.  Unless I'm missing something, there is no way to divide the screen height evenly between the three rows without doing it programmatically, in which case I may as well use a simpler container.

Comment: It's very easy to use a GridView. If the images fit into the screen, it won't scroll. A GridView is simply the "rich cousin" of a ListView.

Comment: Haha @ rich cousin - nice analogy. Sure, I get that - and it works great for dividing screen width.  But in order to fill the screen height I'd have to set the height of the row's views programmatically - so the solution is overly complex and messy, especially when compared to just using a few other containers, like linear layouts, and setting their widths/heights programmatically.

Comment: I'm sure you can fit [this example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) to your needs. This line `imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));` sets the ImageViews size.

Comment: Yes I'm sure I could make it work for me - but it's still unnecessarily complex and messy. I'd have to write a whole new adapter, and then I would STILL have to set the widths and heights programmatically.  See my edit, it's a much simpler solution for my problem.

Comment: Let me tell you that your solution **sucks**. You used `layout nesting`, which is a **performance sucker**. You preferred to go the **easy** way (which is **not always the best** one). I tried to show you the way to do it **better**.

Comment: Hahaha alright buddy sure. Your solution sucks too, though I appreciate you trying to show me. My layout hierarchy was just 2 deep (parent LinearLayout -> child LinearLayout -> Image) and didn't use nested weighting.  The same depth as yours would have been.  

In any case, I switched to a relative layout and just set all my heights and widths programmatically - so now my layout hierarchy is just one deep.  Much, much simpler.

Comment: NO. My solution doesn't. ;)